# Launch page at root level in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created empty project for asp.net MVC4. I created controller named HomeController that has an action Index. I deleted the View folder. I have page Index.cshtml at root. how can I launch it ? Is it possible ? I was trying something like this in index action

return View("~/Index.cshtml");
but no success!

Answer (score 1):

No.

NO.

ASP.NET MVC is a *convention-based application*.  It uses *conventions* to locate resources.  One of the core conventions is that you have controllers named, for example, "XYZ**Controller**" in a folder called **Controllers** that are matched automatically to cshtml views called, in this example, "XYZ**View**" in a folder called **Views**.

If you go deleting these special folders, you *break* the convention.  You break the application.

The solution to your problem is to stop hitting yourself in the head with a hammer.  Don't delete any required folders, don't violate any required conventions.  You should read up on how ASP.NET MVC works prior to tinkering with the defaults provided to you in the template.